# rubyで作ったプログラムで、ユーザーに入力を要求するには

Tags: ruby

`ruby main.rb`でプログラムを実行することはできるようになりました。
簡単な計算や関数を使うこともできるようになりました。

そこで対話式というのでしょうか?そういうものに挑戦してみたいのですが、一気にハードルが高くなったというか、そもそも何をすればいいのかわからない状態です。

まずは以下のようなシンプルなものを作ってみたいので、サンプルコードと解説をお願いできないでしょうか。

```
$ ruby main.rb

your name => : # ここで名前を入力してもらう

hey jony!! # 入力された名前を表示する
```

Comment: Google で [ruby ユーザ入力](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ruby+ユーザ入力)を検索するだけで出てきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば次のような感じですかね。

```
print "your name => : "
name = gets.chomp # ここで名前を入力してもらう
print "hey " + name + "!!" # 入力された名前を表示する
```

[gets](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.0.0/method/IO/i/gets.html) は一行読み込みます。デフォルトでは改行が含まれるので[chomp](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.0.0/method/String/i/chomp.html) で末尾の改行を削除します。